# Z3 - How to set a byte constraint on a BitVec

Tags: python, z3, bitvector

I'm trying to set a list of possible allowed bytes in a BitVec but I'm not sure I'm actually setting the constraints in the right way.

E.g:

Let us have a 32 bit BV called `bv` and a `Solver()` called `s`:

```
s = Solver()
bv = BitVec(8 * 4)
```

I want that each byte can be either `0x2` or `0x34` or `0xFF` so I used `Extract()`:

```
i = 0
while (i < 8 * 4):
    s.add(Extract(i + 7, i, bv) == 0x2)
    s.add(Extract(i + 7, i, bv) == 0x34)
    s.add(Extract(i + 7, i, bv) == 0xFF) 
    i += 8
```

Sadly, `s.check()` returns `unsat`.

I think this is not the correct way to express that those bytes **may be *0x2 OR 0x34 OR 0xFF***.
Did I write the constraints in the right way or my thought process is just plain wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 0
while (i < 8 * 4):
   s.add(Or(Extract(i + 7, i, bv) == 0x2), 
            Extract(i + 7, i, bv) == 0x34),
            Extract(i + 7, i, bv) == 0xFF)) 
i += 8
```

Answer (score 2):

The constraints in a solver are implicitly a conjunction, i.e., you'll have to build a disjunction first and then `s.add(...)` that disjunction.